# jQuery Change video poster based on time of day

Tags: jquery, html, video

I am trying to change the poster of my video based on time of day but it is not working and seems to do nothing and throws no errors.

```
<video width="100%" poster="/poster.jpg"  id="videoPlayer" controls>
<source src="1.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
<source src="1.webm" type="video/webm" >    
<source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">     
</video>
```

jQuery code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
function posterImageTime() {
            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getHours();
            switch(true) {
                case (n > 19) :
                    //Night
                    posterImage = 'night.jpg';
                    break;
                case (n > 16 && n < 19) :
                    //Sunset
                    posterImage = 'sunset.jpg';
                    break;
                default:
                    //Day
                    posterImage = 'day.jpg';
            }
            document.getElementById("#videoPlayer").poster = posterImage;
            //$('#videoPlayer').attr('poster' , posterImage)
        }

});
```

Comment: Any updates on this? Just checking in.

Comment: Yeah...the below answer works but i had a couple questions i just asked today in my comment.

Comment: there is a bit of a noticeable jump when image switches.

Comment: Use CSS to define the width/height of the poster container, maybe even give it a background image too. This will heavily reduce the jump effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its likely because you are only defining the function within document.ready.
Try defining the function outside of ready, and calling that function inside of ready: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rx7kred6/)

```
function posterImageTime() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getHours();
    switch(true) {
        case (n > 19) :
            //Night
            posterImage = 'night.jpg';
            break;
        case (n > 16 && n < 19) :
            //Sunset
            posterImage = 'sunset.jpg';
            break;
        default:
            //Day
            posterImage = 'day.jpg';
    }
    document.getElementById("#videoPlayer").poster = posterImage;
    //$('#videoPlayer').attr('poster' , posterImage)
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    posterImageTime();
});
```

**Side note**:

Don't include the `#` in getElementById.
`document.getElementById("videoPlayer")` will suffice.

Also its good form to declare your variables before assigning their values. You should declare `posterImage` like this: `var posterImage = null;` before your `switch` statement.

Comment: so i would add after var n = d.getHours(); the var posterImage = null;? What does this do? Also should i have an actual poster image in the video or leave it blank?

Comment: Yes its good to define a variable in the scope it will be used. You were defining it within the scope of the switch but then calling it outside of the switch. As for the lag, yes put a default poster image in(maybe as a background image), and that will help the loading transition.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function somewhere: `posterImageTime()`. Now you are just saying. Hey, when you are ready load this function and just stay there without ever being called.

Answer (score 0):

Might be as simple as:

```
document.getElementById("#videoPlayer").poster = posterImage;
```

change to:

```
document.getElementById("videoPlayer").poster = posterImage;
```

You actually need to call the function also:

```
function posterImageTime();
```